# How to adjust scales of multiple plots aligned in one page?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I was trying to put together a panel with 3 plots vertically with same height and width defined in ui.R. However, the outputs layout varies on the grey part due to different length of Y axis text and legend as well.

This is the code defined in ui.R -

```
tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput("plot24_dose", height = 300, width = 1400)),
tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput("plot24_ae", height = 300, width = 1400)),
tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput("plot24_lab", height = 300, width = 1400))
```

[image: plots]

Wondering if what else can be done to set a fixed height and width only for the grey part in plots, regardless of other texts?

Comment: Your question isn't reproducible, so I created data and plotted directly within Plotly - the plot backgrounds were inherently aligned, so I replotted in ggplot2 and converted to Ploltly with the same result. I need more information to help you.  Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). Is your data protected? That's okay, make some fake data -- or shuffle the real data so it's no longer viable before editing your question.